# Laravel MIME Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I came across a hassle, regarding validating the upload of JavaScript files using Laravel,
where the valdation rule is :

```
'javascript_file' => 'required|mimes:js'
```

Which should work as far as i know, since Laravel uses the [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/mime_content_type) to guess the mimes of files, but it doesn't go through, giving me a mime type error when testing with a file with `application/javascript` mime type

Edit: `dd($_FILES)` gives

```
["name"]=> string(7) "data.js"
["type"]=> string(22) "application/javascript"
["tmp_name"]=> string(35) "C:\easyphp\binaries\tmp\php21D0.tmp"
["error"]=> int(0)
["size"]=> int(12253)
```

**Edit 2:**

As @searsaw pointed, seems like the validation guess was wrong.

And after digging in `validateMimes` method in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php`

and dumping the guess variable `dd($value->guessExtension())` i got a `txt` mime -_- which worked

Comment: Try using something like this instead; `'required|mimes:js,javascript'`

Comment: already tried ```javascript``` and ```application/javascript``` but nothing changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. So after a thorough dig through the source code of Laravel, I have figured out how this system works.  Essentially, Validator breaks down the rule from the parameters you passed and, in this case, sends them to the `validateMimes` method on the `Validator` class.  This calls a guesser to find out the extension on the file.  The guesser first guesses the mime-type by cycling through a bunch of other guessers, which use the `finfo` PHP extension to guess the mime-type.  Once it has the mime-type, it passes that mime-type to an extension guesser that guesses extensions based on an array that has the mime-type as the key and the extension as the value.  Then it returns the extension to the original call in the `Validator` class looks to see if the extension is a value in the array of "parameters" you passed to the rule in the first place.  Phew!

Here is the entry the extension guesser is using to guess the extension based on mime-type.

```
'application/java-archive' => 'jar',
'application/java-serialized-object' => 'ser',
'application/java-vm' => 'class',
'application/javascript' => 'js',
'application/json' => 'json',
'application/jsonml+json' => 'jsonml',
```

Right in the middle is the javascript entry.  From the information I have gathered, I am assuming the mime-type guesser is guessing wrong.  It may be interpreting it as a text file and not javascript.  Try making sure the file has the right mime-type attached to it.

I tested what a plain javascript file comes up as using `mime_content_type()`, and it returned `text/plain`.  I'm guessing it's what Laravel is doing too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it didnt work trying ```'data' => 'required|mimes:js,javascript,plain,text/plain',``` and ```dd($_FILES)``` give me ```application/javascript``` as the mime of the file

Comment: as you pointed it seems the guesser is guessing wrong and giving "txt" as the mime -_-

Comment: Well, it looks for extensions. So using something like `mimes:txt` would probably work.

Comment: yeah that's what i have done, but doing ```mime:txt``` for a ```.js``` seems counter intuitive

Comment: I agree. You may want to submit a bug report in the Laravel Github. Someone may be able to find out how to get it working correctly. At least now you where the issue originates.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're on Laravel >= 5.2, there's a new validation method called mimetypes. So, for your case it could be:

```
'javascript_file' => 'required|mimetypes:application/javascript,text/plain',
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel 8. The relevant mime and mimetypes verification (along with other verifications) takes place in

*\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes*

Especially the methods *validateMimes* and *validateMimetypes* are of concern. And yes, the reason for your problem seems to be a wrong mime type guess.