# Multiple file upload and validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to allow multiple files upload, so I did this in my view:

```
{{ Form::file('files[]', array('multiple'=>true)); }}
```

it works, but I can't validate it. For testing purposes I've created this rule:

```
'files' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg'
```

but it doesn't work, it always says the mime type is incorrect, I also tried it with png. 
Can anyone help me please? I also tried to remove the [] from the file input name.
Could be the problem that laravel doesn't support multiple files at validation?

Thanks

Comment: MIME types have a different form, like this: `image/png`, `image/jpeg`... So you're probably specifying wrong MIME types.

Comment: I can't give an answer as my knowledge isn't too good here but first off try changing your validation to `required|image` rather than specifying the mime types of images. (FWIW one of my team has definitely had issues in the past using the `mimes` rule as you are where using `image` fixed it.) Also there is a validation rule `array` that ensures the value is an array. However, I don't know if you can then set rule against the actual elements of the array. The documentation is pretty useless here.

Comment: I've never worked with Laravel as well, but that's what first came to me when I read your question. You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849702/laravel-mime-validation. So this question might be a duplicate of the above-linked one.

Comment: I've also tried it with a validation rule like this: `'files' => 'required|mimes:image/jpg,image/jpeg|max:20000'` but it still not work.

Comment: It should also be noted that `mimes` does not refer to actual mimetypes (sorry @Luka!) but actually some weird interpretation of what the extension should be based on a guessed mimetype. So what Laravel does when validating `mimes` is to guess the mimetype of the file, then to turn that mimetype into a file extension and then validate that against the ones you entered. See Symfony's [MimeTypeExtensionGuesser](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeExtensionGuesser.php) class for the extensions you should use with this rule.

Comment: @user3038158 in the end you may find that you have to do a bit of manual validation here - first ensure that `files` validates against `array` then, if so, iterate over all files and validate each one individually against `required|image`. Then somehow bundle up all the validation errors into one MessageBag to send to the redirect if there's an error.

Comment: @alexrussell: Shouldn't Laravel always detect MIME types of PNG and JPG images correctly? I find it a core feature of every framework. I wouldn't say anything about other less common types, but images would be the most frequently used ones.

Comment: ok the problem is as I expected that I allow multiple file upload. If I loop `Input::file('files')` in foreach and call the validator it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i got the solution by editing the code of the request handler.

```
public function rules()

{
    $rules = [];

    $nbr = count($this->file('field_name')) - 1;

    foreach(range(0, $nbr) as $index) {

        $rules['field_name.' . $index] = 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png';

    }

    return $rules;

}
```